# Query Results in Rule

Tags: jboss, drools

I've made query in JBoss:

```
query "Cars" 
    c : Car()
end;
```

and I want to use in this rule:

```
rule "Ca"
    salience -100
    when
        c : Cars()
    then

end;
```

but anything what I'm doing occurs errors. Are there any possibilities to get query results in rule? I know about this method:

```
org.drools.runtime.rule.QueryResults results = ksession.getQueryResults( "Cars" );
```

but I need to get results in rule. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do that? you can do an accumulate to get the list of all your cars something like this:
when
  $cars: List() from accumulate(Car())
then

You don't need a query for that.